# SQL Query can't find the way to get the result

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I can't find a way to get this result:

```
|-------------|--------|
| username    |  rank  |
--------------|--------|
| takami      |  25    |
| mnk         |  24    |
------------------------
```

I need a list of all users with it's ranks, where the rank is a SUM of count of all questions and answers made by that user, can someone help me making the query?, i tried for hours and i can't make a query get this result.

[image: This is the model of DB]

Thanks very much

Comment: Hi Takami, could we have you post the SQL that you have tried up to this point?

Comment: I don't have any, the problem is that i tried with so many query and deleted all of them because none works...

Comment: Ah; well... would you be able to try one more time and then post that try in your question? :)

Comment: I think that you can use sql 'GROUP BY user_id' and then count...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe there will be answers using sub-queries, but I would like to give you a answer without sub-queries:

```
SELECT user.name, count(distinct question.id) + count(distinct answer.id) from user 
left join
answer on user.id = answer.user_id
left join
question on user.id =question.user_id
group by user.name
```

Please have a look at the [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6fac86/4)